# How to get values of LiveData from repository in viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, room

Quiz app, categories have questions and questions have answers.

I have two queries in the DAO.

In the first one, I get all the categories from the data:

```
@Query("SELECT * from category_table ORDER BY category_id")
fun getAllCategories(): LiveData<List<Category>>
```

In the second one, I get a list of questions and answers by category id:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM question_table WHERE parent_category_id = :categoryId ")
fun getQuestionsWithAnswersByCategoryId(categoryId: Long): LiveData<List<QuestionWithAnswers>>
```

Repository:

```
val getAllCategories: LiveData<List<Category>> = quizDao.getAllCategories()

fun getQuestionsWithAnswersByCategoryId(id: Long): LiveData<List<QuestionWithAnswers>> {

    return quizDao.getQuestionWithAnswers(id)

}
```

This is my viewmodel:

```
val getAllCategories: LiveData<List<Category>>
var questionById: LiveData<List<QuestionWithAnswers>>


 init {
        getAllCategories = repository.getAllCategories

        questionByCategoryId = repository.getQuestionWithAnswersByCategoryId(???????)
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know the categories' id beforehand and need to obtain them from the database.

when I try to obtain a category id in the viewmodel like this:

```
var categoryId = getAllCategories.value[0].categoryId
```

it returns null.

Is there any way to obtain categories id which wrapped in livedata inside a viewmodel?

Comment: `catergoryID` is null, because it is not `observerd` and you can't `observer` livedata from your viewmodel. My question is: Do you need the livedata object in your viewmodel or will it be `observed` from a view?

Comment: Yes, it will be observed in a view, however I also need the data from it in the viewmodel.